# Principal component regression: some loadings are null. Is there any problem?

Tags: r, pca

[image]

I did the principal component regression (PCR) in R . But some loadings are null as figure shows. Is there any problem? How to solve it ?

Comment: What your display shows is no more than that some loadings are not shown. It's most unlikely that that means that such loadings are all  exactly zero (if that's what you mean by "null"). It's more likely that the display filters loadings that are considered small. For example, I see none with absolute value < 0.100. Even if, contrary to conjecture, some loadings really were zero that is not fatal to constructing PCs or using them. (Doing this "in R" is very little information without specifying the precise syntax used.)

Comment: A specific detail: I see sand, silt and clay as variables. It is a common convention to measure sand, silt and clay as % by weight of the total sand + silt + clay. If you did that, or someone else did that to produce these data, one variable is redundant because of the constraint on their sum. But how did you get 8 PCs out of 8 variables in that case?